# Get data in multiple level nested serializer using Django Rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

Need to serialize three models nested in three levels.
There are users assigned areas and these contains point. The users contains multiple areas. Areas have multiple points associated.
Users links areas using many to many relationship. 
Areas Links with point using Foreign in the points.
Users can be assigned to multiple areas. Areas can have multiple points.

User Profile Model

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
      phone_number= PhoneNumberField( unique=True)
      name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
      organisation=models.CharField(max_length=255)
      is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
      is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
      added_by=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1)  
      group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group', null=True)
      areas=models.ManyToManyField('area.Area',blank=True)
      objects=UserProfileManager()
```

Areas Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

 # Create your models here.
class Area(models.Model):
      areaName =models.TextField()
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
      updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL )
      def __str__(self):
         return self.areaName
```

Point Model

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Point(models.Model):
    name =models.TextField()
    area = models.ForeignKey('area.Area', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    latitude=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    longitude=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want a result like following:

```html
   {
        "id": 3,
        "phone_number": "+919999999999",
        "name": "Ak",
        "organisation": "sp",
        "group": 1,
        "areas": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "areaName": "Area 51",
                "user": 1
                points:[{
                    
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "areaName": "Rrea 343",
                "user": 1
                point:[{}]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "phone_number": "+918888888888",
        "name": "Chitra Sahu",
        "organisation": "sd",
        "group": 2,
        "areas": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "areaName": "Area 51",
                "user": 1
                point:[{
                     
                    latitude:'23.2323',
                  longitude:'23.2323'
                },
                {
                   
                    latitude:'21.1223',
                  longitude:'32.34345'
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "areaName": "Rrea 343",
                "user": 1
                point:[{
                     
                    latitude:'23.2323',
                  longitude:'23.2323'
                },
                {
                   
                    latitude:'21.1223',
                  longitude:'32.34345'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
```

So Far I have tried the following

```html
class AreasSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
 model=Area
 fields=('id','areaName','user')
class AreasUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 areas = AreasSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

 class Meta:
  model = UserProfile
  fields = ('id','phone_number','name','organisation','group','areas')
class AreasUserPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 areasUsers=AreasUserSerializer()
 class Meta: 
  model=Point
 fields =('id','areasUsers' )
```

Views

```html
'''Fetch list all question '''
class AreasPointsUsersListApiView(ListAPIView):
 
 
 serializer_class=serializers.AreasUserPointSerializer
 def get_queryset(self):
  queryset=UserProfile.objects.all()
  user=self.request.query_params.get('user_id',None)
  if user is not None:
   queryset = queryset.filter(id=user)
  #if areas is not None:
  # queryset = queryset.filter(areas=areas)
  return queryset
```

.py

This code is not working properly.
I need to serialize it so that the Users consists Areas based on Many to Many relationship. These areas are linked to point using the foreign key in Point.

> EDIT

Edit: 
Areas serializer

Comment: can you add the views too?

Comment: @JPG I have added the view also.

Comment: Looks like the top-level serializer is `AreasUserLocationSerializer` which you've not included. Mind adding that? You're not the right track defining multiple Serializer classes... it'll just be a matter of getting the nesting and fields right.

Comment: @DwightGunning Its the same `AreasUserPointSerializer`. Changed it

Comment: Ok so the `AreasSerializer` is not shown. This makes it hard to see what's really happening. Can you please post all your Serializer classes and also add a sample of what the response looks like currently?

Comment: @DwightGunning AreasSerializer was added

Comment: I am guessing the serializer isn't emitting any Points at the moment? Again, it'd sure help if you could provide an example of the current output. `AreasSerializer` likely needs a custom "Serializer Method" field to list the related Points since it's the model relationship is reversed. See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: @DwightGunning Thanks I resolved it.  Posted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved this using LocationSerializer which invoked by AreasSerializer.
I am sharing the code snippet. It was pretty easy.

```html
 
class PointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
   model = Point
   fields=('id','latitude','longitude')
class AreasLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 points = PointSerializer(many =True, read_only=True)
 class Meta:
  model=Area
  fields=('id','areaName','points','user')

 
class AreasUserLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 areas =AreasLocationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
 class Meta: 
  model=UserProfile
  fields =('id','phone_number','name','areas')
```

Comment: Recommend marking your answer as correct as it solves the problem.

Comment: @DwightGunning Two days to go

Comment: @AkhilSahu, I am having a similar issie. Just like your `Point`, I have nested post data. But it's not a different model. In the serializers create method I want to get those data like `validated_data.pop('point')` or `validated_data.get('point')` . But I can not do this because it is nested. Is there any hack for this?

Comment: Get the parent data and you will get nested data in it in the same process. s = validated_data.pop('point') 

s['nested']['data']